# How do I specify disk space (volume size) of a master node when spinning up a cluster?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

This documentation shows the default volume sizes based on the instance size:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-storage.html

My question is how do I specify the volume size to be bigger when starting up the cluster.

Currently, I'm manually changing it from the EMR page after the cluster is up and running:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `VolumeSpecification` JSON to get this done. I **have not tried this for the master node**. I had used it for the core node and task node, But I believe this concept can be extended to the master node as well.

The fields inside the `VolumeSpecification` JSON are self-explanatory, So I am not adding their explanation here. You can read them here [VolumeSpecification explanation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-emr-ebsconfiguration-ebsblockdeviceconfig-volumespecification.html)

I am adding a code snippet that can help you how do we exactly use this configuration.
I am using the standard `boto3 library` in my code. I have a lambda function that spawns the EMR cluster, but having a lambda function to spawn EMR is, **not a must**, and you can choose your own alternative.
The code snippet is:

```
from datetime import datetime
import boto3
'''
    This code snippet is used to create an EMR cluster.
'''

def create_emr_cluster(event, context):
    conn = boto3.client("emr")
    today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    cluster_id = conn.run_job_flow(
        Name='Your_EMR_name',
        ServiceRole='EMR_DefaultRole',
        JobFlowRole='EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
        VisibleToAllUsers=True,
        LogUri='s3://your-s3-path-where-you-want-cluster-logs/%s/' % today,
        ReleaseLabel='emr-5.17.0',
        ScaleDownBehavior='TERMINATE_AT_TASK_COMPLETION',
        Applications=[{'Name': 'Spark'},
                      {'Name': 'Hadoop'},
                      {'Name': 'Hive'},
                      {'Name': 'Hue'}]
        Instances={
            'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': False,
            'Ec2KeyName': 'your-key-name-here',
            'Ec2SubnetId': 'your-subnet-id',
            'InstanceFleets': [
                {'Name': 'Master Node',
                 'InstanceFleetType': 'MASTER',
                 'TargetOnDemandCapacity': 1,
                 'InstanceTypeConfigs': [{
                     'InstanceType': 'c4.xlarge'
                 }]
                 }, {
                    'Name': 'Core Node',
                    'InstanceFleetType': 'CORE',
                    'TargetOnDemandCapacity': 1,
                    'InstanceTypeConfigs': [{
                        'InstanceType': 'r5.2xlarge',
                        "EbsConfiguration": {
                            "EbsBlockDeviceConfigs": [
                                {
                                    "VolumeSpecification": {
                                        "SizeInGB": 64,
                                        "VolumeType": "gp2"
                                    },
                                    "VolumesPerInstance": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }]
                }, {
                    'Name': 'Task Nodes',
                    'InstanceFleetType': 'TASK',
                    'TargetSpotCapacity': 100,
                    'InstanceTypeConfigs': [{
                        'InstanceType': 'r5.2xlarge',
                        'BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice': 50,
                        'WeightedCapacity': 16,
                        "EbsConfiguration": {
                            "EbsBlockDeviceConfigs": [
                                {
                                    "VolumeSpecification": {
                                        "SizeInGB": 32,
                                        "VolumeType": "gp2"
                                    },
                                    "VolumesPerInstance": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }, {
                        'InstanceType': 'r5.4xlarge',
                        'BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice': 50,
                        'WeightedCapacity': 40,
                        "EbsConfiguration": {
                            "EbsBlockDeviceConfigs": [
                                {
                                    "VolumeSpecification": {
                                        "SizeInGB": 64,
                                        "VolumeType": "gp2"
                                    },
                                    "VolumesPerInstance": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }]

                }]
        }
    )
    return cluster_id['JobFlowId']
```

Answer (score 0):

An Amazon EMR cluster always consists of one or three master nodes. You can't scale the number of master nodes after you initially configure the cluster. You can only scale core and task nodes in a cluster