# Can we clone a terminated emr cluster using lambda function and will there be any dfferences in the new cluster?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-emr

I have come across answers saying that it is not entirely possible to clone a cluster using lambda boto3. And some saying that it is possible only through the aws cli. And I have come across run_job_flow function but it involves passing all the parameters separately. And couldn't figure how do we use the terminated cluster along with run_job_flow to get a new clone. If you can please suggest me a way to do this. Thank  you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option1:** If you have **enough permissions** in the AWS console, then in simply one click you should be able to get a new cluster, exactly the clone of the terminated cluster.

I am attaching the screenshot for your reference.

[image: Clone option in the EMR]

**Option2:** You can also do the AWS CLI export highlighted in the above image so that you can use them using the command line. paste the output of the CLI export in a file and run it from a place that has enough access to launch the EMR.

**Option3:** You can also write an AWS lambda function which will be responsible for spawning the EMR. You can find multiple examples of this online.

Comment: ajay i'm actually looking for a modified "option 3". My exact question CAN WE CLONE USING LAMBDA ?? If so, please share the process

Comment: hii all i've been waiting for the update. If you can, please contribute.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by `clone using lambda`. My understanding is if you have a lambda that is able to launch EMR, then spawning lambda multiple times is as good as cloning a terminated EMR.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66822699/how-do-i-specify-disk-space-volume-size-of-a-master-node-when-spinning-up-a-cl/66849127#66849127 for an example to launch the EMR